# How do I passivise "be"?

Tags: tense, passive-voice

I want to reward you -> You should be rewarded.

I want to be nice to you -> You should be `be'd nice to`.

What's the fancy linguistic way to describe this gap in English, and what's the right way to say it?

Comment: I am a native speaker.

Comment: Then [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I guess english stackexchange would be better suited for this question since it has only to do with english.

Comment: It's already there. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/229661/15299

Comment: How about "You should have someone be nice to you." or "You should have me be nice to you."?

Answer (score 2):

It is all simple: in English only the transitive verbs (with some rare exceptions) can have passive forms, and **be** isn't a transitive verb. You are going to have the same "gap" if you decide to make a similar transformation to "I want to become as good as you", "I want to come to you," "I want to die without you," etc. `Become`, `come`, and `died` are intransitive verbs, they cannot have passive forms (*be become, *be come, *be died), so the transformation of that kind cannot be done.

By the way, there should have been `been` instead of your `*be'd`, but anyway, that sentense is impossible even with `been`.

Comment: I don't think it should have been "been". "Rewarded" is in the simple past tense (although it's being used as a past participle here), while "been" is in the perfect aspect. The simple past tense of "be" is "was". Either way, though, it doesn't work, for the reasons you gave in your answer.

Comment: @Zgialor - You're wrong. "Rewarded" is **not** in the simple past tense, it is the past participle of "to reward", and "been" is the past participle of "to be", so "rewarded" and "been" are in the same form. I can prove that: if we use "forgive" instead of "reward" we'll have _I want to forgive you -> You should be forgiven_, not _*You should be forgave_, "forgiven" is the past participle, or: _I want to hide you -> You should be hidden_, not _*You should be hid_, "hidden" is the past participle, the same will happen with any other verb which has the past simple and past participle different.

Comment: Ah, whoops... My bad.

Comment: @Zgialor - What confused you is the fact the with "reward" the past simple tense and the past participle are the same, "rewarded". No verb in the past simple tense can be used after "be", but the past participles can. More examples:  _I want to choose you -> You should be chosen_, not _*You should be chose_, "chosen" is the past participle, _I want to eat you -> You should be eaten_, not _*You should be ate_, "eaten" is the past participle, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Sorry.